# Which matrix do we use to calculate principal components in PCA? $X^T X$ or covariance matrix of $X$?

Tags: probability, statistics, visualization

I am reading Principal Component Analysis (PCA) from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).
Under the details section, it states that the principal components are just eigenvectors of $X^T X$ where $X$ is the data matrix.

However, this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429962/covariance-v-correlation-matrix-based-pca) suggests that principal components are covariance matrix's eigenvectors.

I am confused now.
To obtain principal components in PCA, which matrix do we use? $X^T X$ or covariance matrix of $X$?

Comment: Where's the contradiction?

Comment: No contradiction. I am not sure which matrix to use when I want to calculate principal component. Is it data matrix or its covariance matrix? Do we get the same set of principal components for either matrix?

Comment: Isn't $X^T X$ the covariance matrix?

Comment: Opps. I think I need to polish up my knowledge on multivariate covariance matrix. Can you give a reference on showing that $X^T X$ is the covariance matrix of $X$?

Comment: Is it? I don't know. To me, this looks like asking about singular vectors and eigenvectors.

Comment: "Consider a data matrix, $X$, with column-wise zero empirical mean"....